Turn-off chart title with Python in ArcGIS Pro 3.2
I would like to maximize the size of the box-plot graphs by turning off the automatic Chart titles, which I don't need at all, so that I can print the 5 graph images pasted into the layout on 1 pdf sheet. The script snippet is part of a python toolbox and the full boxplot images will be successfully generated if I don't try to turn the Chart title off. However, if I paste my attempts at CIM definition it runs to error, or nothing happens.
How can this be resolved within the script toolbox?

    plot_list= [
        {"name": "DEM_plot", "yAxis": "DEM", "ytitle": "DEM (m)", "place": 272},
        {"name": "SLOPE_plot", "yAxis": "slope_p", "ytitle": "SLOPE (%)", "place": 216},
        {"name": "Wet_plot", "yAxis": "Wet", "ytitle": "Wetness", "place": 160},
        {"name": "NDVI_plot", "yAxis": "NDVI_mean", "ytitle": "NDVI", "place": 104},
        {"name": "Temp_plot", "yAxis": "temp_n", "ytitle": "Temp (C)", "place": 58},
    ]
    for types in plot_list:
        arcpy.AddMessage(types["name"])
        censusLayer = (lyr_plot)
        c = arcpy.Chart("{}".format(types["name"]))
        c.type = 'boxPlot'
        c.xAxis.field = 'SS_GROUP'
        c.xAxis.title = "Zone"
        c.yAxis.field = "{}".format(types["yAxis"])
        c.yAxis.title = "{}".format(types["ytitle"])
        c.showOutliers = False
        c.dataSource = lyr_plot
        c.addToLayer(censusLayer)
        c_cim= lyr_plot.getDefinition('V3') #from this point do not work
        for f in c_cim.charts:
            f.generalProperties.showTitle=False
        lyr_plot.setDefinition(c_cim) #until this point
        c.exportToSVG(os.path.join(output_folder,"boxplot{}.svg".format(tipus["name"])), width=850, height=270)
        aprx.createPictureElement(lyt_hat, MakeRec_UL(5, int("{}".format(types["place"])), 200, 55), os.path.join(output_folder,"boxplot{}.svg".format(tipus["name"])))


